# Regions already registered error on navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a TabControl region in Shell.xaml:

```
<TabControl Name="TabRegionControl" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="TabRegion" />
```

The user can click a button to open a new tab, which calls:

```
RegionManager.RequestNavigate("TabRegion", new Uri("Search?X=1", UriKind.Relative));
```

The new tab is created in the tab control and displays the view. The view contains multiple sub regions (and a view for each of those regions). This works so far. When the user clicks the button again, I get the error saying that the regions are already registered.

I know this is happening because the regions cannot be registered again in the same region manager. I've read that scoped regions can be used to resolve this. As best as I can figure out, I replace the RequestNavigate above with this to create a scoped RegionManager:

```
SearchViewModel svm = new SearchViewModel();
IRegion detailsRegion = _regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"];
SearchView view = new SearchView(svm);
IRegionManager scopedRegionManager = detailsRegion.Add(view, null, true);
svm.ScopedRegionManager = scopedRegionManager;
svm.LoadViews();
```

I believe I have to manually load the views into my sub regions in the method LoadViews(), but the sub regions are not displaying.

Here is how they are defined in Search.xaml:

```
<ContentControl Background="White" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0"        
Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="SubRegion1"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  />
```

As a starting point, the scopedRegionManager does not seem to have any of my sub regions in it's region collection.

*edit*

I am now seeing the sub regions in the region collection of the scoped region manager. The sub views are still not displaying, here is how I am trying to load the sub views inside the LoadViews method, which might be completely off course:

```
ViewModelSub1 vm = new ViewModelSub1();
IRegion detailsRegion = _regionManager.Regions["RegionSub1"];
SubView1 sView = new SubView1(vm);
IRegionManager detailsRegionManager = detailsRegion.Add(sView, null, false);
detailsRegion.Activate(wsView);
```

I'm new to WPF and MVVM. Any assistance or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated as I'm utterly lost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using the Prism framework, however I feel that their Regions should only be used for Application Layout (`MenuRegion`, `NavigationRegion`, `ContentRegion`, etc), and not Navigation. Using them for Navigation means letting the View control the application flow, and I feel that is a job for the ViewModels.

To create something like you outlined, I usually have a parent ViewModel which contains

- `ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> Tabs`
- `int SelectedTabIndex`
- `ICommand AddNewTabCommand`

My TabControl definition looks like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}" />
```

and the `AddNewTab` command simply adds a new object to the `Tabs` collection and sets it as Selected

```
void AddNewTab()
{
    var newTab = new TabAViewModel();
    Tabs.Add(newTab);
    SelectedTabIndex = Tabs.IndexOf(newTab);
}
```

To determine what View to display, I usually use DataTemplates

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TabAViewModel}">
    <local:TabAView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TabBViewModel}">
    <local:TabBView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've implemented your suggestion, but I'm facing a different problem now. I'll post with more details shortly.

Comment: Basically, the view I am trying to display in the TabControl contains multiple sub-regions. My understanding is that to inject the views into these sub-regions, I need access to the regionManager object - but I don't have that object available because of the way I'm binding the views to the TabControl. How would I go about injecting those views without a regionManager object? Or is there a smarter way to handle this?

Comment: I educated myself regarding DataTemplates, problem solved. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @user1117578 Glad you got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 5):

We had the same problem and we've tried using the scoped region manager - without any success. So we ended up doing a brute-force solution that works, but probably not the intended use;

```
public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.RegionManager.Regions.Remove("regionname");
}
```

That is; when navigating away from the view/view model that contain the 'scoped' region, we just remove the region from the region manager. When the view is instantiated next time, it will add the region to the region manager without any exceptions being thrown.