# How can I implement "View Model First" using Prism and Unity?

Tags: c#, mvvm, unity-container, prism, caliburn.micro

**Clarification**
I am working with an MVVM solution. I have a 1 to 1 mapping between ViewModels and Views. All solutions I have seen follow a view first approach where the View type is resolved by an IoC container and has a ViewModel as a dependency. I need to reverse that somehow.

**Original post:**

I am currently trying to refactor a simple database viewing application from Caliburn Micro to Prism ***(which I am very new to)***. The application currently utilizes a ViewModel-First approach and the ShellViewModel maintains a list of ViewModels that is bound to a TabControl. 
I can not find how to implement a similar approach in Prism. All solutions I have seen use a view first approach, but I have multiple states all mapping to one type of view and need to keep those states separate. 
[image: Outline of application]

Is there a way I can configure prism to automatically inject a view when a viewmodel is assigned to a region?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're looking to use an implicit DataTemplate. That is simply a DataTemplate defined in XAML with a TargetType, but no Key. WPF will automatically use that DataTemplate to draw the specified object when it is encountered in the Visual Tree, such as when it tries to render a TabControl where ItemsSource is set to a collection of ViewModels. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8645746/302677) for an example if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rachel pointed me to a solution in her comment to the original question.
Instead of trying to implement special prism functionality and prism regions, I have gone with a more straight forward MVVM implementation using DataTemplates.

ViewModel outline:

```
public abstract class ContainerViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    public ItemViewModel ActiveItem { get; set; }

    protected virtual void Add(ItemViewModel item) { ... }
    protected virtual void Remove(ItemViewModel item) { ... }
    protected virtual void Activate(ItemViewModel item) { ... }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveItem}">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Table.TableName}"    />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:QueryViewModel}">
                        <local:QueryView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code project article (ignoring the part about child containers): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640573/ViewModel-st-Child-Container-PRISM-Navigation

Comment: This article is informative, but does not appear to follow MVVM (the demo solution infact does not contain any views at all) and states at the bottom that it is a niche solution for WPF/Silverlight applications.
I will see how I can go about clarifying my question.